# How do I create an image rollover link using php and css

Tags: php, css, image, rollover

I'm trying to create an image rollover button to place within a php file. The css is below...now what php script would I use to display the button?

```css
#quotebutton {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    width: 147px;
    height: 35px;
    left: 830px;
    top: 400px;
    background-image: url ("http://sickwebmedia.com/wp-content/themes/gridportfolio/images/get-a-quote.png");
    background-repeat: none;
}

#quotebutton a:hover {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    width: 147px;
    height: 35px;
    left: 830px;
    top: 400px;
    background-image: url("http://sickwebmedia.com/wp-content/themes/gridportfolio/images/get-a-quote-over.png");
    background-repeat: none;
}
```

Comment: CSS applies to HTML, not PHP...

Answer (score 2):

Why are you attempting to place this in a PHP file?

A couple of things off the bat tho:

1. You don't need the quotes in your CSS url("") tag. It can just be url(http://imagehere.com/sup.png)
2. The hover scope does not need to have every attribute re-defined. For example, you can just do this: 

   `#quotebutton a:hover {
       background-image: url(urlhere)");
       }`

Edit: Nikola has a more appropriate answer for implementation. I created an example for you of what Nikola's talking about however:
http://jsfiddle.net/XAtGP/

Cheers. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use html code, or php script that outputs the html code:

```
<a id="quotebutton" href="#">Quote</a>
```

In CSS, **#** stands for **ID** of some element.

If you are planning to use more than one such button on a single page, you should change #quotebutton to .quotebutton (with dot at the beginning) and use it like this:

```
<a class="quotebutton" href="#">Quote</a>
```

where **.** in CSS stands for **CLASS** of an element.

HTML classes can be used by many elements while ID is the unique identifier of the element and can't be used 2 times on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

css: if anchor tag is nested within #quotebutton

```
#quotebutton>a{
position: fixed;
display: block;
width: 147px;
height: 35px;
left: 830px;
top: 400px;
background-image: url ("http://sickwebmedia.com/wp-content/themes/gridportfolio/images/get-a-quote.png");
background-repeat: none;
}

#quotebutton>a:hover {
background-image: url("http://sickwebmedia.com/wp-content/themes/gridportfolio/images/get-a-quote-over.png");
}
```

html example:

```
<div id="quotebutton">
    <a herf="#"></a>
</div>
```

if not and #qoutebutton is the anchor the css is a follows:

```
a#quotebutton {
position: fixed;
display: block;
width: 147px;
height: 35px;
left: 830px;
top: 400px;
background-image: url ("http://sickwebmedia.com/wp-content/themes/gridportfolio/images/get-a-quote.png");
background-repeat: none;
}

a#quotebutton:hover {
background-image: url("http://sickwebmedia.com/wp-content/themes/gridportfolio/images/get-a-quote-over.png");
}
```

html example:

```
<a id="quotebutton" href="#">quotebutton</a>
```